# using size_t inside for loop throwing error "std::length_error"

Tags: c++, c++11

I had encountered an error inside for loop, if str.size() = 1 then it's throwing error as

> terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::length_error'
> what():  basic_string::_M_create

but if str.size() is anything more than 1 then everything goes well.
Also when I changed size_t to int everything goes fine. Why?

```
for (size_t i = str.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        excess3(str[i]);
```

Here str is vector of string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`size_t` is an unsigned type, so the condition `i >= 0;` will always evaluate to true, and the loop never ends.

Either replace `i >= 0` with `i != 0` (and make sure to never enter the loop with an empty vector), or change the loop variable from `size_t` to a signed type like `int`.

Answer (score 1):

size_t is unsigned. If str.size() == 1 then i is initialized to 0. the first time through the loop is ok. The second pass decrements i and makes it very large in the unsigned world. On a 32 bit system it would be 0xFFFFFFFF, which is bigger than zero of course. Try ssize_t instead of size_t. It is the signed variant. That's also why int works.